# Bring Window To Top/Active

Tags: vb.net

I need some help with a small little program that I am making for a game. I can't get it to work so it switch to the game and then press the buttons that I want. It finds the window but just don't switch to it or make it active. Am I using the correct function?

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Declare Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Integer) As Integer

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'Dim Hwnd As Long = BringWindowToTop("Aftermath v0.9.0  (build: Apr 15 2015 14:38:12) - final D3D9")
        Dim Hnd As Integer = Win32.FindWindow(Nothing, "Aftermath v0.9.0  (build: Apr 15 2015 14:38:12) - final D3D9") & BringWindowToTop(Hnd)
        If (Not Hnd = 0) Then
            SendKeys.Send("{enter}")
            SendKeys.Send("/ginvite " & Chr(34) & TextBox1.Text & Chr(34))
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Error")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim curItem As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
        SendKeys.Send("/ginvite " & Chr(34) & curItem & Chr(34))
        SendKeys.Send("{enter}")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Dim curItem As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
        SendKeys.Send("/gaccept " & Chr(34) & curItem & Chr(34))
        SendKeys.Send("{enter}")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            Me.ListBox1.SetSelected(i, True)
        Next
        'Dim curItems As String = ListBox1.SelectedItems.ToString()
        'SendKeys.Send("/ginvite" & Chr(34) & curItems & Chr(34))
        'SendKeys.Send("{enter}")
    End Sub

End Class
```

I would also love if you could help me with my list box. I want it so it prints our each string with `Chr(34)` in front and behind it.

The code that I currently have (doesn't work):

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        Me.ListBox1.SetSelected(i, True)
    Next
    'Dim curItems As String = ListBox1.SelectedItems.ToString()
    'SendKeys.Send("/ginvite" & Chr(34) & curItems & Chr(34))
    'SendKeys.Send("{enter}")
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this about [tag:vb.net] or [tag:vba]?

Comment: It's vb.net. Sorry I am just really new here this is my first post.

Comment: Then edit the question to remove the [tag:vba] tag.